# ffmpeg, first second of cut video part freezed

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this to cut a part out of a mp4 file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:36:18 -to 00:39:50 output.mp4
```

It works good but the video image is always freezed in the beginning for 1 second.

Doesnt matter which video file I try and cut a part out of, it takes like 1 second before the video start.

Heres an example:

Why?

Comment: It seems your youtube link is down, could you please keep the example live such that the question remains useful for future visitors?

Answer (score 8):

The **order of the parameters** is very important on `ffmpeg`.
Try this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:36:18 -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -to 00:39:50 output.mp4
```

It seems that setting the `-ss` parameter **before** `-i` sets a keyframe at the beginning of the newly generated video.
Or so I understand from the Wiki page [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking).

Comment: Minor note: That's the wiki, not the [official documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html). The wiki articles are written by users to supplement the docs, so they may contain less accurate information.

Comment: This was the answer which helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The video freezes because you aren't cutting at an [I-frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types), while using stream-copy mode. You'll have to re-encode the video, or choose a different start point, which happens to be an I-frame.

Comment: Is there any way to easily locate an I-frame in order to perform the cutting with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17688356

Comment: Thanks you, but this other one solved my day: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking (just change the order of `-ss` in the command line).

Answer (score 2):

What works for me was:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i video.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac cut.mp4`